# How to add print results to another file

Tags: java, file

I am try to get what it printed from `text.txt`, make a new file that is `text2.txt` and put the print results in that file. All I know how to do is read and use the first one.

```
try{
    sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
}
catch (Exception e){

    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Look at classes extending [Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) or at [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).

Comment: Not 100% clear what it is you are asking, but if you want to FILE2 in the event that printing to FILE1 fails out with an exception, it sounds like a use-case for a logging system such as log4j (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/).

Answer (score 1):

Mena is right, you should use chaining of classes from within the java.io package. You'll have to adjust text.txt and text2.txt in order to fit into your application, but this should get the job done:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Copier{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("text.txt")));
      File outputFile = new File("text2.txt");
      outputFile.createNewFile();
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

      String line = null;
      while(true){
          line = br.readLine();
          if(line == null)
              break;
          bw.write(line);
          bw.newLine();
      }
      br.close();
      bw.close();
  }
}
```